# Blank field error check

Tags: php, javascript, localhost

I've got a .php registration file that can successfully insert 4 new fields into a user database in my localhost but whenever I add an empty field error check it will stop working.
If I don't use an empty field error check all 4 blank values will be added into my user table in localhost.
Here's the code in my .php file:

```
    <div class="contact">
            <div>
                <h4>Registration Form</h4>
            </div>

            <div>
                <table bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <h4>All fields are necessary and are not to be left empty</h4>
                </br></br>
                <font color="white">Name</font><input class="test1" type="text" id="txNm" value="">
                <font color="white">Username</font><input class="test1" type="text" id="txUsn" value="">
                <font color="white">Password</font><input class="test1" type="password" id="txPwd" value="">
                <font color="white">E-Mail</font><input class="test1" type="text" id="txEml" value="">
                <input class="test2" name="Submit" type="submit" value="" id="submit" onClick='submitUser();txNm.value="";txUsn.value="";txPwd.value="";txEml.value="";'/>

            </table>
            </div>

        </div>
```

the submitUser function will then jump over to a js file:

```
    function submitUser(){
var name = $('#txNm').val();
var username = $('#txUsn').val(); 
var password = $('#txPwd').val(); 
var email = $('#txEml').val();


var finalData = {
    nm: name,
    usn: username,
    pwd: password,
    eml: email
};



$.post('submitUser.php', finalData, function(resp){
    if(resp == 'success'){
        alert('Thank you for register.');
        getUserList();
    }
});
```

}
then it will jump again go to a submitUser.php file containing the rest of the code
here's the contents:

```
    $nm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nm"]);
$usn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["usn"]);
$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pwd"]);
$eml = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["eml"]);

$q = "INSERT INTO userdb (name, username, password, email) VALUES('$nm','$usn','$pwd','$eml')";

     if(!mysql_query($q, $con)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    echo mysql_error();
}else{
    echo 'success';
}


mysql_close($con);
```

the thing is, everytime I add an empty field error check nothing will happen, if I remove it then the whole registration process will continue but well...even if the fields are all empty.

My code is:

```
   `if(empty($_POST['txNm'])) {
die('You need to enter a value for the Name field');
}`
```

what is wrong with my empty field error check code?

Comment: I think `empty($_POST['txNm'])` should be `empty($_POST['nm'])` because you're passing this as the post data `var finalData = {
    nm: name,
    usn: username,
    pwd: password,
    eml: email
};`

Comment: with your code my code will register but no "success" message appears neither with the empty field error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be typo error:

```
-----------------'nm'
if(empty($_POST['txNm'])) {
die('You need to enter a value for the Name field');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(empty($nm)) {
die('You need to enter a value for the Name field');
}
```

Also these might need to be changed to:

```
$nm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txNm"]);
$usn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txUsn"]);
$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txPwd"]);
$eml = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txEml"]);
```

Comment: I've added that to my submitUser.php and nothing happened. Then I removed it and I could register again. I just don't get it, it seems right, but nothing happens. It's like that one piece of code is preventing the registration process from happening. With your second one my fields will get registered with blank fields no matter what I fill in to the text boxes, also, no 'success' message or the blank field message error appears

Comment: yes and it works now, I've given that function to all 4 fields and it won't register anything if any of the 4 is empty but no alert message appears. I tried changing 'die' to 'alert' but it's the same.

Comment: Try changing it to     `echo 'You need to enter a value for the Name field';`

Comment: Also if this worked, don't for get to mark as the correct answer.